# passing all the items of listbox in the richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

how can I pass the items of listbox to richtextbox?. I have multiple items and I want it to display in the richtextbox. this items is like a receipt. it display the items along with its amount.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a way to do it, using `LINQ`:

```
Dim Items As String() = 
    From s As String In ListBox1.Items

RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Items)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems doing this with a listbox, is that listboxes store the items as objects and uses the ToString method of each object to display a representation of that object.

Something like this should work:

```
RichTextBox1.Lines = (From o In ListBox1.Items
                      Let ostr = o.ToString
                      Select ostr).ToArray
```

This way if you use objects that can't be implicitly cast as string it will still work.  Or, if you use custom objects all that's required is a ToString override in the class.