# Listbox1 add all the items to richtextbox in the same format

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, listbox, richtextbox, loading

I'm trying to get all the `ListBox1` items and have them go to the `RichTextBox1`. I want it in the same format that it's in the `ListBox1`. I've tried different code and they seem to give extra blank lines in between items. So far I've thought of this but it give extra blank lines.

```
Dim counter As String

counter = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0

If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
    Do Until ListBox1.SelectedIndex = counter
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & ListBox1.SelectedItem
    Loop
End If
```

Comment: Looks like you need to `Trim()` your strings. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LINQ` to select all the items and join on `Environment.NewLine`:

**.Net >= 4.0**

```
Me.RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, (From item As Object In Me.ListBox1.Items Select Me.ListBox1.GetItemText(item).Trim()))
```

**.Net >= 3.5**

```
Me.RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, (From item As Object In Me.ListBox1.Items Select Me.ListBox1.GetItemText(item).Trim()).ToArray())
```

Comment: gives error for me : Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Object,System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'.

Comment: Meant to post this: Dim Items As String() = 
    From s As String In ListBox1.Items

RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Items)

Comment: @RandomShelly No, The `ListBox.ObjectCollection` contains `Objects`.

Comment: @ Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå : thanks for the information, i downvoted your answer since it gives error for me, i mentioned it in the comment, you can edit it.

Comment: And the error is because you're using a `.net` version below `4.0`.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - you are right...  but why it is giving that error... even though it shouldn't...  you are using an object in the GetItemText (item)- which returns a string... but the enumerator is what causes the issue?  I wasn't sure, so that is why I copied the code I pasted under here in the comments from that link I referenced in my 'answer'...

Comment: @RandomShelly It's because starting with `.Net 4.0` you can join on `IEnumerable(Of String)`. Prior to that you could only join on `String()` See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå AH! Makes sense...  Thanks for clearing that up!  I kept looking at it and wondering WHY isn't this working?!?!!

Comment: Removed the downvote since it works properly, am using .net fW 3.5. +1 for this answer

Answer (score 0):

This is **because initially the richtextbox is empty**. Hence `RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & ListBox1.SelectedItem` will add a `New Line` first and the add the second element of list to the richtextbox, this is because you incremented the **selected index value by 1** before adding to the richtexbox. So your code can be used in an effective way as follows:

```
    Dim counter As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        Do Until ListBox1.SelectedIndex = counter
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & ListBox1.SelectedItem & vbNewLine
            ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
        Loop
    End If
```

Comment: May i see the output which you have got? where/in which event you include this snippet?

Comment: @Sample Look at your code. `Dim counter As String`? Really? String?

Comment: @  Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå : thanks for the correction. i corrected it

Comment: Here's a puzzle for you: Why did I use `GetItemText(obj)` as opposed to `SelectedItem` or `Items(n)`?

Answer (score 0):

you are adding a vbNewLine before you add the ListBox text... you should put that at the end of the line `RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & ListBox1.SelectedItem & vbNewLine` and you also shouldn't increment your selected index value until after you add the line...

Alternatively, You can do this..

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 
RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & ListBox1.Items(i) & vbCrLf 
Next
```

OR this SO question has a few good examples using LINQ and condensed query code...
[passing all the items of listbox in the richtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288852/passing-all-the-items-of-listbox-in-the-richtextbox)

Comment: +1 since it working. but it is in a different way as in the question

Comment: @Sample - Yes, it is different - that is why I put 'alternatively' - I tend to *try* to write shorter code... Doesn't always work, but I rarely use counters that I have to manually increment - it has bitten me more than than once.. that famous endless loop when forgetting to add or subtract...

Comment: still puts spaces between the items

Comment: @user3329318 - Did you click on that link to the other SO thread about this? ...that first answer with the "RichTextBox.Lines = " might work?  You're saying this puts in the text and a blank line and then the next text??  Are there CRLF characters in the ListBox String?

Answer (score 0):

try saving the listbox to a file using a streamwriter and writeline(), then opening it into a text box using streamreader and readtoend()
    `'assuming you have the default names
    dim reader As streamreader, writer As streamwriter
    writer = new streamwriter("TMP")
    for each x as object in listbox1.items
    writer.writeline(X)
    next
    writer.close()
    reader=new streamreader("TMP")
    textbox1.text=reader.readtoend()
    reader.close()`